# session issue in php front end login and admin panel login

Tags: php

I am working with sessions, when I login from front end as well as into admin panel and when I log out from front end I am also getting logged out from admin panel. so kindly suggest me the solution

Comment: recode your logout process or and your buisness logic from logger class

Comment: Keep different session names for both side and unset frontend session when you do frontend logout and same for backend

Comment: Your code so far? That said do not destroy the session. Unset the var for the login but not those of admin panel

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you are using `session_destroy()` function for logout. Which will destroy all active `sessions`.

Please destroy individual admin sessions and customer sessions like

**For admin**

```
unset($_SESSION['admin])
```

**For customer**

```
unset($_SESSION['customer])
```